# Django template tag to display Django version

Tags: python, django, templates, tags

What is the simplest way to create a Django template tag which displays the Django version on a template?

I want to put the following in a Django template and have it output the Django version (in my case, base.html):

```
{{ django_version }}
```

I know that the following Python code outputs the Django version in a shell, but am confused about where I should put this code and how I should call it from the template:

```
import django
print django.VERSION
```

**UPDATE:** I have tried the following in views.py, but nothing shows up in the template:

```
import django    
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

    def base(request):
        django_version = django.VERSION
        return render_to_response('base.html', {'django_version': django_version} )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured this out (currently using Django 1.3) — I needed to **append the function name 'django_version'** to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS tuple in **settings.py**:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (  
    # ...  
    'myproject.context_processors.django_version',  
)
```

**context_processors.py** (thanks to [zsquare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256145/django-template-tag-to-display-django-version/4256485#4256485)):

```
import django
def django_version(request):
    return { 'django_version': django.VERSION }
```

**urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^$', 'direct_to_template', {'template': 'base.html'}),
)
```

Put the following in your templates, such as **base.html**:

```
{{ django_version }}
```

Comment: Might be due to the newer version now but I didn't have to set any urls.py config like you have there.  I was able to call `{{ django_version }}` directly assuming I made the change in my settings.py and context_processors.py

Answer (score 5):

A simple context processor would do what you want

context_processors.py

```
import django
def django_version(request):
    return { 'django_version': django.VERSION }
```

Dont forget to include this context processor in your settings under `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`

Comment: This sounds good. 

I've put the above in /mysite/blog/context_processors.py and then put the following in /mysite/settings.py (I had to add the first django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth line because without it I got an error):

<code><pre>TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
 'mysite.blog.context_processors.py',
)
</code></pre>

Still nothing shows up in the HTML page powered by the template containing {{ django_version }}.

Comment: You should be adding mysite.blog.context_processors (without the .py)

Comment: My bad…I have changed it to mysite.blog.context_processors, but still no go. I think there must be something else causing the problem. I will keep at it. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You should provide the django.VERSION as variable to the template via the template context. I recommend following the django tutorial or read the django docs if you don't know how to do this.

Comment: I'm a novice programmer and have looked at the tutorials, but can't seem to get this to work. I have updated the example with some code I attempted in views.py.

Comment: Are you sure the template is displayed? When you add some additional information to the template, e.g. `The django version is: {{ django_version }}`, you say your result is `The django version is: `?

Comment: Yes, the template is displayed. Any modifications to the words 'The django version is:' shows up, but {{ django_version }} doesn't output anything.

Comment: For one thing I wouldn't use `django.VERSION()` but rather `django.VERSION` :)

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question and changed django.VERSION() to django.VERSION. Still, nothing is output.

Comment: Also, you can't just use django.VERSION without importing django.

Comment: Have now added import django, too, and still no output from {{ django_version }}. Thanks for your help, I will keep at it and update this if/when I find a solution.

Comment: Not sure and probably not the solution, but have you tried changing the variable name django_version to something different?

Comment: Yep, tried changing to a different variable name but still no go.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `django.get_version()` to get the django version in string, the `django.VERSION` returns a tuple.

```
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 11, 12, u'final', 0)
>>> django.get_version()
'1.11.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

context_processors.py

```
import django

def django_version(request):
     return {
       'django_version': django.get_version() # django.VERSION (returns a tuple.)
     }
```

Include this context processor in your project `settings.py` file under `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (  
    #########  
    'myproject.context_processors.django_version',  
)
```